# Why are Binary Search Trees (BST) created using a node data structure instead of arrays?

Tags: binary-search-tree, binary-heap

Most examples of BSTs I have seen are of the form

```
Class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Key key;
    Value value;
 }
```

But BSTs looks like a specific form of Binary Heaps with a extra constraint , namely the left child value should be less than parent value which should be less than right node value.

Binary heaps are easily implemented using arrays. Why not create BSTs using arrays making sure that this extra rule is maintained ? What are the disadvantages of doing so ?

Comment: People do implement BSTs using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: You can't just dynamically change the size of an array.

The size of an array can't just be changed afterwards. If you would use an array you'd have to enlarge it or shrink it depending on what is added or removed which would cause unnecessary overhead since you would have to copy the content from the old array to the new array whenever you do that.

Using nodes that use references or pointers allow you to just (re)assign `left` and `right` to a new element accordingly whenever you insert or set it to `null` (or something similar) if you remove an element which gives you a much more dynamic structure.

Comment: In that case doesn't binary heap have the same problem ? But they still seem to be the preferred choice to do priority queues ...

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: I was just wondering if problem of resizing the array was the only reason to go with a node structure in case of BST ? Put differently, if I know that there will only be fixed number of elements in the BST (say less than 100) , then a array is good choice to implement BSTs instead of nodes ?

Comment: I might miss something but imho the only reason for not going with an array is the inflexibility it entails. Say you have an array of 100 elements stored in an array and want to add one. You'd have to copy the whole elements into another array which means you are using twice as much memory for that copy task than necessary. However, if you are e.g. on an embedded system you might want to get rid of the overhead that a node brings (pointers to left and right etc). In the case were you know the maximum size of your tree one might want to use an array for that.

Comment: Stuff like that always depends on the task and on the resources you've got for it. As you know both ways are fine and would work - Nodes and Array - you just have to analyze your specific problem and make a choice that best fits your requirements.